# Which states had ballot initiatives to legalize marijuana in 2016?

Tags: united-states, election, referendum

538 had sporadic news in their live blog about individual state initiatives to legalize marijuana in 2016.

That led me to be curious: is there a full list of states where that topic was on the ballot this year?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether or not this is the complete list, but this is what I came across:

Arizona, Massachusetts, Nevada, Maine, and California all had "Recreational Usage" bills on the ballot.

Arkansas, Florida, Montana, and North Dakota all had "Medicinal Usage" bills on the ballot.

[Source.](http://www.thecannabist.co/2016/07/14/definitive-guide-us-states-voting-recreational-medical-marijuana-inovember-2016-election/58063/)